# Using PresentViewController instead of storyboard doesn't display the cell data?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

The cell data for a specific tableview I am trying to create displays texts and images if it is called by storyboard but not if the PresentViewController (no storyboard) is used. The cells are still clickable and lead to another view with images, but the images and text on the actual tableview are not displaying.

This is how my TableViewController is created:

```
TableViewController *myVC = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithDismissButton];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: How are you creating the view controller you are presenting? Also, are you executing any code in the prepareForSegue method in the presenting view controller? That is not executed if you use presentViewController:...

Comment: I've pasted some code that shows you how it is created. I'm not using any segues here, do you have to?

Comment: And what's the code in initWithDismissButton?

Comment: self= [self init];                                                     return self;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the view controller in that way you are not loading what you have in the storyboard. Use `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tableViewControllerIdentifier"];`

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster has suggested, the problem is likely that segues trigger your prepareForSegue method. In storyboard segues, that's where you configure the destination view controller before displaying it.

In the code you posted above, you would insert your configuration between the alloc/init call and the presentViewController call.

So if you need to pass an array to the table view controller to serve as the model, the code might look like this:

```
TableViewController *myVC = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithDismissButton];
myVC.tableDataArray = arrayForTableVC;
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences when using storyboards between manually allocating view controllers:
• In storyboards: the view controller is initialized using `initWithCoder:`
• Manually: whatever init method you call. For Table view controllers you should call `initWithStyle:`

There's also a big difference when reusing cells:
• In storyboard: You design a prototype cell in interface builder and you must to give it a cell identifier. This cell will allocated using this identifier in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
• To create a cell manually you have to choose a style during initialization or to create all the custom controls and add them as subviews to the `contentView` property of the cell yourself (unless you're using a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and then you have to do it in the subclass initializer).